# Why is there no C port of LAPACK 3.5.0 available?

Tags: c, fortran, lapack, emscripten

My goal is to use LAPACK with Emscripten. Emscripten is capable of transforming C code to JavaScript. But unfortunately, LAPACK 3.5.0 (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) is only available in FORTRAN95.

The CLAPACK project (http://www.netlib.org/clapack/) is basically what I want: a C version of LAPACK. But this one is outdated; the latest is 3.2.1.

So my question now is: why is there no newer port of LAPACK to C? Are there any suggestion how to achieve my goal anyway?

Thanks in advance!

I managed to port LAPACKE, the LAPACK C-wrapper to javascript. Nevertheless I can't work with it, because the wrapper uses internal the FORTRAN routines. How would I embed these in emscripten?

E.g. the function LAPACKE_cgbcon uses LAPACKE_xerbla which is only available in FORTRAN. Why would I benefit from porting a wrapper?

Comment: Because nobody did it yet? Because it´s work too...

Comment: Most of us in the target audience for libraries such as LAPACK are comfortable calling Fortran from C and *vice-versa*.  Personally I don't see the point of translating well-written code from language A  to language B (with all the possibilities of errors in translation) when it is (relatively) easy to call A from B.  Note that CLAPACK seems to have been translated using `f2c` -- a route that is open to you.

Comment: yes, but f2c currently only supports F77!

Answer (score 5):

The new version uses Fortran 95. There exist no automatic translation tool from it to C.

There is a new tool called [fable](http://cci.lbl.gov/fable/) available, but it also supports only a small subset of Fortran 90. They claimed to be able to translate part of LAPACK 3.2.1, but there are no news about full  and more recent LAPACK.

Do you really need the code in C? Can't you just call it from C, possibly using an existing C wrapper?

For the official C API see http://www.netlib.org/lapack/#_standard_c_language_apis_for_lapack

Comment: I will give it a try. Didn't thought of the possibility to just use a C wrapper instead!

Comment: I managed to port LAPACKE, the LAPACK C-wrapper to javascript. Nevertheless I can't work with it, because the wrapper uses internal the FORTRAN routines. How would I embed these in emscripten?

Comment: Sorry, I don't no anything about javascript and I suggest you to start a new question with this specific javascript problem. In your original question you didn't mention it at all.

Comment: One reason to use a C or C++ version is if you're using Visual Studio and Visual C++ runtime on Windows. Gcc will produce an executable using a different ABI and runtime to MSVC. The Intel fortran compiler I think will work with MSVC but it's not free. LLVM kind of supported fortran through dragonegg but that's not being maintained and I haven't found a single usable build for Windows.

Comment: @kjbartel Try to install gfortran mingw, compile a dll and link it with your code with libgfortran and libquadmath. I did it only for simpler libraries, but it worked well. This of course does not solve the OP's problem with emscripten, but when I extended a game compiled with VS with my mingw gfortran compiled dll I did not see any ABI problems. (I used `bind(C)` and `iso_c_binding`).

Comment: @VladimirF Yes you can use dynamic linking doing as you say. However, you can't debug the code and you can't use static linking to reduce the size of your generated lib / executable. Depends what you're trying to do.